# Am I eligible for a Marie Curie (MSCA) postdoc fellowship, given my details?

Tags: postdocs, europe, marie-curie

I'm a non EU citizen and a long term resident of France (holder of a ten year carte séjour = residence permit)), who received his PhD in mathematics from an American university in **October 2013**, and subsequently worked as a postdoctoral researcher for four years (three years in France, one in the US). This was followed by a **few years (2018-2020) spent in industry**, and since **September 2021, I've been working as a teaching-only lecturer** in mathematics at a French engineering school.

Being very passionate about research and looking to get back to mainstream academic research, I'm planning to apply for an MSCA postdoc fellowship with a EU based institution outside France, but before I'm just checking to make sure that I'm eligible to apply. It seems from the [MSCA postdoctoral eligibility page](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/actions/postdoctoral-fellowships#:%7E:text=For%20Postdoctoral%20Fellowships%20in%20research,or%20a%20Euratom%20Associated%20Country.) that the eligible applicants must have at most eight years of experience in the EU (look at the sentence about 'third countries' in the screenshot).

[image]

So strictly speaking, it seems I've only three years of post - doctoral research experience in the EU, so I should be eligible to apply. Could someone please verify this? Thank you!

**ADDENDUM:** The reason I've asked this question here is that I've already tried to look for [contact information for Marie Curie postdocs](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/contact), and there doesn't seem be a clearly written email address that'd answer such questions. If you go to the link, it'll ask you to go to the site of [European Research Executive Agency](https://rea.ec.europa.eu/rea-fosters-excellence-science-european-year-skills_en), which gives you a bunch of irrelevant information, nothing to do with contact emails. It's confusing that they put up so much info to skip through in order to just get a hold of the contact info.

Next, I googled "marie curie postdoc 2023 contact email", and from [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=marie%20curie%20postdoc%202023%20contact%20email&sxsrf=APwXEdfaVEu84soFvL7CQnMTEA2IJMoEWg%3A1684750610513&ei=EkFrZP_wHpmgkdUPgcaumAg&oq=marie%20curie%20postdoc%202023%20contact&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgoIABBHENYEELADOgQIIxAnOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEIoFEIYDOggIIRAWEB4QHToECCEQFToHCCEQoAEQCkoECEEYAFC-Bli6GWDbJmgBcAF4AIABe4gBmQeSAQQxMS4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), I see that

[image]

So I emailed them at this address, but no reply yet! Hence I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you asked the MSCA?

Comment: I sent them an email today!

Comment: @user438383 The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a dedicated email address to ask questions, as I'm going to put in an edit now.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think the only real thing to worry about is the number of years post your PhD. One of the eligibility criteria is a maximum of 8 years post PhD. But in your case, if I understand correctly you finished your PhD in 2013, which seems to make you 10 years post PhD.

I don’t know whether they have anything for returning scholars. My best advice will be to write to your intended host institution and they will probably have someone there to answer your query.

Alternatively you could join the Master Class at TU Dreseden that holds next week and someone there will hopefully give you a better answer
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7048975828939853824/

Comment: Thnaks, but it's "maximum 8 years of research post-PhD", it isn't "maximum 8 years of research post-PhD". This means that teaching or industrial positions not related to academic research won't count. I've gone through their website and they've a self-assessment tool to evaluate oneself, and I qualify so far, since I've only done four years of post PhD research.

Comment: Oh that’s great. I will definitely encourage you to apply. You should definitely begin now because writing the proposal actually takes a fair bit of time.