# How do I contact Marie Curie postdoc by email? I did significant research but all in vain!

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, marie-curie

This question is very much linked to [this question of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/196214/am-i-eligible-for-a-marie-curie-msca-postdoc-fellowship-given-my-details), that got no reply. However, the subject of this present question is very different.

I've already tried to look for [contact information for Marie Curie postdocs](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/contact), and there doesn't seem be a clearly written email address that'd answer such questions. If you go to the link, it'll ask you to go to the site of [European Research Executive Agency](https://rea.ec.europa.eu/rea-fosters-excellence-science-european-year-skills_en), which gives you a bunch of irrelevant information, nothing to do with contact emails. It's confusing that they put up so much info to skip through in order to just get a hold of the contact info.

Next, I googled "marie curie postdoc 2023 contact email", and from [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=marie%20curie%20postdoc%202023%20contact%20email&sxsrf=APwXEdfaVEu84soFvL7CQnMTEA2IJMoEWg%3A1684750610513&ei=EkFrZP_wHpmgkdUPgcaumAg&oq=marie%20curie%20postdoc%202023%20contact&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgoIABBHENYEELADOgQIIxAnOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEIoFEIYDOggIIRAWEB4QHToECCEQFToHCCEQoAEQCkoECEEYAFC-Bli6GWDbJmgBcAF4AIABe4gBmQeSAQQxMS4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), I see that

[image]

So I emailed them at this address, but no reply yet! Hence I'm asking here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's my understanding that eligibility questions do not go to a central Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions office, but rather the National Contact Points - see the second paragraph on the first page you link to:

> If you need help to prepare your application or have questions about the specific requirements of the job offers funded under the MSCA, follow the link to reach out to the [MSCA National Contact Points](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/support/ncp;sortQuery=country;countryGroups=MS;countries=;functions=All%20Functions,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) in your country.

If you click that link you'll get a list of all the National Contact Points, you can filter it for particular countries and schemes, which should give you a few contact e-mails to try.

The e-mail address you say you mailed is not an EU address associated with the MSCA itself, but rather a particular institute's call for applications for MSCA roles to be hosted by them, so they probably are not a relevant person to contact.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I accepted your answer - it's quite helpful! You're right in saying that the  eligibility questions do not go to a central Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions office, and I do wonder if any question goes though it at all? I've yet another question, that I'm wondering about - can we submit more than one proposals to MSCA postdoc fellowships? Thanks again!

Comment: @ScienceMan What Stephen McMahon is writing is that the National Contact Points are to be contacted for *any* question. We don't know why the eui.eu e-mail address is given at all on any website, but do know that the EU has a scheme where they offload the work to answer questions to national contact points completely. These contact points receive training so that they know the funding programs very well.

Comment: @ScienceMan I don't think there's any general MSCA contact e-mail address at all for such queries. Regarding the fellowship question - if you mean the scheme where the postdoc applies for their fellowship (previously 'Individual Fellowships'), then no, it's 1/round I believe. But MSCA does also fund postdocs through some other schemes (e.g. [CoFund](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/actions/cofund)), which some people call 'MSCA Postdoctoral Fellowships' in job ads. These are normal postdocs, which you can apply to multiple of, although are less individually prestigious.